# The 2D Array Index access, with step value

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like:

```
a =np.array([[1,2,3,5,8,7,2,1,3,5,1,2,20,21],[3,8,3,9,8,7,10,1,3,5,1,2,20,21]])
```

requirement:

> need to access index value with given step. For an example step value 3.
> Only index value not an elements value.

Required Output:

```
[[0,3,6,9,12],[0,3,6,9,12]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with 1D array with range function. Its okay with 1D

Comment: Repeat it in a list comprehension.

Comment: if you want you can add your code to the post and i'll help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list comprehension to repeat the range for each row.

```
a =np.array([[1,2,3,5,8,7,2,1,3,5,1,2,20,21],[3,8,3,9,8,7,10,1,3,5,1,2,20,21]])
indexes = [list(range(0, a.shape[1], 3)) for _ in range(a.shape[0])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,5,8,7,2,1,3,5,1,2,20,21],[3,8,3,9,8,7,10,1,3,5,1,2,20,21]])
step = 3
indices = [np.arange(0, arr.size, step) for arr in a]
```

print(indices):

```
[array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12]), array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12])]
```

If you want lists instead of np arrays, just use `.tolist()` like:

```
[np.arange(0, arr.size, step).tolist() for arr in a]
```